# Divide a Point in Elliptic Curve Cryptography

Tags: elliptic-curve

I'm using Elliptic Curve to design a security system. P is a point on elliptic curve. The receiver must obtain P using formula k^-1(kP). The receiver does not know P but knows k. I need to compute k^-1(R) where R=kP. How can I do this using Point Multiplication or Point Addition.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question you have! I was happy to implement from scratch Python solution for your task, see code at the bottom of my answer.

Each elliptic curve has an integer order `q`. If we have any point `P` on curve then it is well known that `q * P = Zero`, in other words multiplying any point by order `q` gives zero-point (infinity point).

Multiplying zero (infinity) point by any number gives zero again, i.e. `j * Zero = Zero` for any integer `j`. Adding any point `P` to zero-point gives `P`, i.e. `Zero + P = P`.

In our task we have some `k` such that `R = k * P`. We can very easily (very fast) compute [Modular Inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of `k` modulo order `q`, using for example [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

Inverse of `k` modulo `q` by definition is such that `k * k^-1 = 1 (mod q)`, which by definition of modulus is equal `k * k^-1 = j * q + 1` for some integer `j`.

Then `k^-1 * R = k^-1 * k * P = (j * q + 1) * P = j * (q * P) + P = j * Zero + P = Zero + P = P`. Thus multiplying `R` by `k^-1` gives `P`, if `k^-1` is inverse of `k` modulo `q`.

You can read about point addition and multiplication formulas [on this Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication).

Lets now check our formulas in [Python](https://www.python.org/) programming language. I decided to implement from scratch simple class `ECPoint`, which implements all curve operations (addition and multiplication), see code below.

We take any ready-made curve, for example most popular 256-bit curve `secp256k1`, which is used in Bitcoin. Its parameters can be [found here](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf) (this doc contains many other popular standard curves), also you can read about this specific curve on [Bitcoin Wiki Page](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1).

Following code is fully self-contained Python script, doesn't need any external dependencies and modules. You can run it straight away on any computer. `ECPoint` class implements all curve arithmetics. Function `test()` does following operations: we take standard `secp256k1` params with some base point `G`, we compute any random point `P = random * G`, then we generate random `k`, compute `R = k * P`, compute modular inverse `k^-1 (mod q)` by using function `modular_inverse()` (which uses extended Euclidean algorithm `egcd()`), compute `found_P = k^-1 * R` and check that it is equal to `P`, i.e. check that `k^-1 * R == P`, print resulting `k^-1 * R`. All random values are 256-bit.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVZbb6M4FH7Pr/BotVvo0AQISUg1GS3kIu3DRm13tS9VZZHgpqgECDhN@PWdc2xDoUlGo63aGp/L5@Nz88lK/pImfTfL399D9kzYZh1qgUFW@m2HwM9v5IXzrLjt9VjSPUSvUcbCKOim@aaHu978yFkSspDO9@s4ClmQ0CDepHnEX7YCIE8NkhukgKUwCIeFkwnBEwxiGcQUv5YQPbxEMSM5@TIhpjy9AtB2AKKDHiCF0ds2DTWBq9dSAh8ECjyK3JAduSZFza2O5WiB4nJpHuP7PBGHIARPBbWDroBT9nGQ0yh5Y3nB0CtA@kW//K2Ut/uYR1kcrQMevbEKS0BspEfArMrpCC9YQVGwnJMNmUzQSVf/BfGekSTlRADwaAWOWpXSxH3x5ap5l4L8joxOZx0DDplP79Io4dLsPwVtyyDooSDgRf9KuLaOwZaj3nC7BANN7ah3LisXPKQZHiAhkmDLGijRs6DgPa4Kts7swfDVuvrgn7hyFfE1oHUjLv34T6V0QeVwOHQBeCM8Dx/2zZvdzcLnlngGPjaPC/VD/8/HXH5M7UULOUDkFmUFlFGLchSnj8b@fDgcAc54NvV9b0oHA88c2uMBnc7dkembI2raY38xnfnUnk3ntjsb08F4YbvWwKfWcOFao7HbQi4FsuP2vZk3GlF76PWnznBABzPPWQASNeeWZbqeSxcza@Q7jku9oTsYONaYjqfOaGa6cEHfMmeO30be/aLH5tT3vDlYO6TewnE9s@9TfzGzB3N3Smdmf@hYzkfoWFywduxVoi@CWBVFI/VU4mpHg5SG6hiZQXayROoEpFBUEadUK1j8DDkspD2D@AZZgrRBrkEtZ1mQQxqSf/P9p/xUvLZdS2wlgNfF2ljqLZ7Eluegnx5rQaZD6S3Jc5oTBpVDHluiT0/nrq450Is8cn1N@uQrsUew83FnS6wvn/OrUiuFEPSyo9S9QRDY3BBfakLJQWfVWsoiHdsOugQkQPRzRy@B4yB8/xy3RE6WHrRjdSdp11c8T1vCaumk1yOO0YQXLgSbxOqrdanWo1pLtaLTa/uVcz/nRBCGdUqk/IXljaCDbh3f6sxlzb0DxDuAvIf1vqzkGjYIOCTIj7KZTHdHvP79kQRJCChiU7ZTC18pTQPBayL@CRfp@FwhPvR3DfQgIugfEYSflI/CKiFo92UbAzMBr/AZBLuRVqAoCCiptkRZSUgQ4IJg2ZY5W6KN@FWh2zVrT1T5SfXm8EReDJXYN2tREm4giT5sUfyaIOcIrPS2tyA@Uv0PYt2e1AXC5BCLFtSJKj7Ip7rNSaLFlErfv09I@wHDQ5TZzSMvP7MYU/HAQh9MTp/pM7NKcuppluXK06cIBc@1MFpDLBspX6c/RvejZFpX8Su63yirpWyNMgf0E0vY7mLEsXlG0CnEDIpNlCX7LcsDzrTHE79rlaGqJnVDkeoyLWuSV5E83bgA5Fcifq21rEjLmrSrSDv9ST/JsABb9upMekk3n33pMFU7YubkrOCaAo22WQoNNYdWkspZGoYjrHiYh8T2DjNWcLu4wN@GaRb59k0IYjtQ9dn9GNIaU5iMyuvPQYTMA8i8Yr/qyAjtk5Di4Z@z7tUgD@AVkHxojrG1wkQhZDmaosgwXEaYEzgnUiomRUq3QZRQqgZF6ZTO@/sP)

```py
def egcd(a, b):
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm
    ro, r, so, s, to, t = a, b, 1, 0, 0, 1
    while r != 0:
        ro, (q, r) = r, divmod(ro, r)
        so, s = s, so - q * s
        to, t = t, to - q * t
    return ro, so, to
    
def modular_inverse(a, mod):
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse
    g, s, t = egcd(a, mod)
    assert g == 1, 'Value not invertible by modulus!'
    return s % mod

class ECPoint:
    @classmethod
    def Int(cls, x):
        return int(x)

    @classmethod
    def std_point(cls, name):
        if name == 'secp256k1':
            # https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1
            # https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf
            p = 0xFFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFE_FFFFFC2F
            a = 0
            b = 7
            x = 0x79BE667E_F9DCBBAC_55A06295_CE870B07_029BFCDB_2DCE28D9_59F2815B_16F81798
            y = 0x483ADA77_26A3C465_5DA4FBFC_0E1108A8_FD17B448_A6855419_9C47D08F_FB10D4B8
            q = 0xFFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFE_BAAEDCE6_AF48A03B_BFD25E8C_D0364141
        else:
            assert False
        return ECPoint(x, y, a, b, p, q)
    
    def __init__(self, x, y, A, B, N, q, *, prepare = True):
        if prepare:
            N = self.Int(N)
            A, B, x, y, q = [self.Int(e) % N for e in [A, B, x, y, q]]
            assert (4 * A ** 3 + 27 * B ** 2) % N != 0
            assert (y ** 2 - x ** 3 - A * x - B) % N == 0, (
                x, y, A, B, N, (y ** 2 - x ** 3 - A * x) % N)
            assert N % 4 == 3
            assert y == pow(x ** 3 + A * x + B, (N + 1) // 4, N)
        self.A, self.B, self.N, self.x, self.y, self.q = A, B, N, x, y, q
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        A, N = self.A, self.N
        Px, Py, Qx, Qy = self.x, self.y, other.x, other.y
        if Px == Qx and Py == Qy:
            s = ((Px * Px * 3 + A) * self.inv(Py * 2, N)) % N
        else:
            s = ((Py - Qy) * self.inv(Px - Qx, N)) % N
        x = (s * s - Px - Qx) % N
        y = (s * (Px - x) - Py) % N
        return ECPoint(x, y, A, self.B, N, self.q, prepare = False)
    
    def __rmul__(self, other):
        other = self.Int(other - 1)
        r = self
        while True:
            if other & 1:
                r = r + self
                if other == 1:
                    return r
            other >>= 1
            self = self + self
    
    @classmethod
    def inv(cls, a, n):
        return modular_inverse(a, n)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(dict(x = self.x, y = self.y, A = self.A,
            B = self.B, N = self.N, q = self.q))
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        for i, (a, b) in enumerate([
                (self.x, other.x), (self.y, other.y), (self.A, other.A),
                (self.B, other.B), (self.N, other.N), (self.q, other.q)]):
            if a != b:
                return False
        return True

def test():
    import random
    bits = 256
    P = random.randrange(1 << bits) * ECPoint.std_point('secp256k1')
    k = random.randrange(1 << bits)
    R = k * P
    found_P = modular_inverse(k, R.q) * R
    assert found_P == P
    print(found_P)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Output:

```py
{
    'x': 108051465657467150531748691374311160382608428790397210924352716318223953013557, 
    'y': 4462548165448905789984443302412298811224817997977472205419179335194291964455,
    'A': 0,
    'B': 7,
    'N': 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663, 
    'q': 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337
}
```

Comment: Doesn t this result depends on the curve being used?

Comment: @user2284570 Yes, knowledge of curve params is needed to solve this task, knowing just X, Y of a point is not enough. You need to know parameters Q (order) of a curve to compute k^-1, and you need to know params A and N to do multiplication k^-1 * (k * P).